# Can't push to github through proxy

Tags: git, proxy, github

Please help, I'm trying to push to github from my workplace...
I've tried this:

```
myuser@somewhere /c/sites/mrquery (master)
$ git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com:breienr/mrquery.git

myuser@somewhere /c/sites/mrquery (master)
$ git http-push origin master
error: Cannot access URL origin/, return code 22

myuser@somewhere /c/sites/mrquery (master)
$ git config --get http.proxy
proxy:8080
```

but i still get "error: Cannot access URL origin/, return code 22"

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/) and [here](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2009/09/23/git-error-pushing-via-http-return-code-22/), your proxy server probably doesn’t have WebDAV enabled.